# find code for classpath in gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, classpath

In Android Stdio,We can see as following.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

I know that the this code is for gradle dependencies with **jar**.
But I cannot find the this **jar** locally.
How can I find this **jar**?

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle caches by default will be here

`~/.gradle/caches/jars-<number>/<hash of jar>/<jar name>.jar`

or

`~/.gradle/caches/modules-<number>/files-<number>/<group id>/<artifact id>/<version>/<file hash>/<jar name>.jar`

Comment: Sorry,I canot find them as your paths